# Is there an efficient representation for ordinal numbers?

Tags: language-agnostic, representation, ordinal

I am working on an event processing framework that could be improved if I had an efficient way to do computations with ordinal numbers.

In Java syntax, I'm looking for:

```
class Ordinal {
    static int compare(Ordinal o1, Ordinal o2) { }
    static Ordinal suc(Ordinal o) { }
    static Ordinal add(Ordinal o1, Ordinal o2) { }
    static Ordinal mul(Ordinal o1, Ordinal o2) { }
    static Ordinal pow(Ordinal o1, Ordinal o2) { }
    static Ordinal omega() { }
    static Ordinal zero() { }
}
```

The only approach I've thought of so far is to literally represent the possible operations as data which is a lot like representing integers as linked lists and so doesn't feel terribly good.

Does anyone know of such a thing?

**Further information**:

[Ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) [numbers](http://blog.plover.com/math/ordinals.html) are a mathematical concept, which is usually focused on the idea of well-ordered sets, but I am hoping to use them as a way to produce numbers that "keep getting bigger".

So for example, 1, 2, 3 ... are all less than ω. Then ω + 1, ω + 2, .... are all less than 2ω, is less than 3ω, ... which are all less than ω², is less than ω³ ... all less than ω^ω, and so on. This is why representing them efficiently seems to be tricky... simple place-value representation quickly runs out, and the runs out again, and again, and again.

The reason that I thought I would like to have ordinal numbers in my code is that they serve as a way of putting a cap on the depth of a recursive computation, where recursive computations can get very deep, infinitely deep and "beyond" (as in, more than ω). Consider a list of recursive functions, where the ith function has depth i, and then a function that does a fold over the list ... its depth is ω, but then we can add one more step to that, and one more again, getting ω + k, and thus another fold gives 2ω, and we can generalize this process to required ω², and so on.

Now, the reason I want to *compute* with ordinals, is that, if you label the nodes of a DAG with ordinals that respect both topological ordering and depth, one thing you might want to do is perform a kind of graph search that visits the nodes in increasing order of their ordinal tag. I'm not 100% sure that this is how I want my code to work, but it was an approach I was considering so I wanted to see if it was reasonable to go down this road. It's looking more and more like I should reconsider my approach, in which case this question might be moot, but is still interesting for curiosity.

Comment: Can't you use some big integer library for your representation? In Java, this would be BigInteger. Your wrapper would make sure that no negative numbers ever occur and provide the distinguished `omega` value.

Comment: The problem with BigInteger is that omega would have to be finite... so you could in theory get there buy repeated suc.

Comment: Well, I write an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is language agnostic, I take the freedom to show a proposal how to do this in Java, should be easily transferable to any language that has a notion of object identity.

```
class Ordinal {
    private BigInteger value;   // invariant: value is positive
    // this is only used to construct omega once
    private Ordinal() { value = BigInteger.ONE.negate(); }            
    public final static Ordinal omega = new Ordinal();

    public Omega(BigInteger v) {
        if (v.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        value = v;
    }
    public BigInteger value() {
        if (this == omega) // .... throw exception?
        else return value;
    }
    // example implementation of suc
    // note that it'll never equal omega
    // because omega is initialized with (-1)
    // In addition, there is one and only one, non copyable omega.
    public static Ordinal suc(Ordinal o) {
        if (o==omega) then return omega;
        else return new Ordinal(BigInteger.ONE.plus(o.value));
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a non copyable singleton object `omega`, whose value does not and cannot equal that of any other value.
The implementation of the functions requires identification of `omega`, this is as easy as a reference equality check. For example, in `suc` we let `suc omega` be `omega` and otherwise add 1.

Comment: This answer is very helpful because it shows I need to clarify more what I mean. I've added further explanation to the question.

Comment: Ok, your explanation makes it clearer now. Tt looks like you need something that is known in functional programming as an algebraic datatype.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [some work has been done on this topic in Agda](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mhe/papers/ordinals/ordinals.html).

I haven't looked deep enough to see whether it is practically usable or mostly theoretical.